# C header file format

Tags: c, format, header-files

Trying to get a grip on proper format for setting up header files for my external functions that I'm doing for school.

In the .h file I place the `#ifndef <token> #define <token>` and `#endif` pre-processor calls around my prototypes but additional `#defines`, for use within the function itself, go inside the .c file or in the .h?

When adding the whole package to my main program do I just need to add at the top of my main program  `#include "name_of_function_pkg.h"` or does there need to be a reference to the .c file within the header file too?

**[Edit]  Added the code for you as requested.  The whole things works fine but just want to write it by the standard everyone else does.**

My main() file:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "utils.h"

    //  DEFINED Values

    #define FALSE 1
    #define TRUE 0

    //  MAIN CODE
    int main()
    {

    //  Local Variables
        int success = TRUE;

        float fValue,fConvert;
        float fSrcFactor,fDstFactor;

        char cSourceCurrency;
        char cDestCurrency;
        char cNewline;

    //  User Input
        printf("Enter source currency: ");
        scanf("%c%c",&cSourceCurrency,&cNewline);
        printf("Enter destination currency: ");
        scanf("%c%c",&cDestCurrency,&cNewline);
        printf("Enter the value: ");
        scanf("%f",&fValue);

        fConvert = convert( cSourceCurrency, cDestCurrency, fValue);


    //  Output
        if(fConvert == -1)
            {
                printf("There was an error with the input.");
            }

        else printf("%c%.2f = %c%.2f",cSourceCurrency,fValue,cDestCurrency,fConvert) ;


    //  Exit    
        return 0;

    }
```

My utils.h File:

```
#ifndef UTILS
#define UTILS 

float convert( char cSourceCurrency, char cDestCurrency, float fValue );

#endif
```

My utils.c File [truncated]

```
// Should these defines be in the .h file?
#define CDN 1
#define YEN 95.04
#define EUR 0.69
#define E2Y 137.69

#define FALSE 1
#define TRUE 0


float convert( char cSourceCurrency, char cDestCurrency, float fValue )
{
//  Function Variables
int success = TRUE;

float fConvert; 
float fSrcFactor,fDstFactor;


//  Error Checking
if( (cSourceCurrency!='Y') && (cSourceCurrency!='$') && (cSourceCurrency!='E'))
    {
        success = FALSE;
        return (-1);
    }
if( (cDestCurrency!='Y') && (cDestCurrency!='$') && (cDestCurrency!='E'))
    {
        success = FALSE;
        return (-1);
    }
```

Comment: Rather than explaining what you have please *show* what you have.

Comment: And the meaning of "reference to the `.c` file within the header file" is unclear....; please explain more by showing what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the C preprocessor is working and handling the `#include` directive. Read the wikipage on [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) within the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

It is a purely textual thing. The preprocessor replace the `#include` by the included file, and expands the `#define`-d macros which occur later.

You might even avoid any `#include` and copy and paste code, but that would be a very bad habit.

In practice, put in the headers all the declarations shared between more than a single file, and also all the needed `#define`

Show us your code, and also look at existing practice (e.g. look into the source code of some free software coded in C).

Answer (score 0):

No, you never need to reference to a C file to link files together.  You only need to #include header files.  However, make sure all the files you need are in the same folder. Whether or not you want to use #define in the header file or the C file is dependent on scope.  If you're only going to use your defined values in main then #define it in main, but if they will be used in other c files such as in function definitions then put it in the header.  Just be wary of what you already defined.